# MVC .NET OrWhere Query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I want to perform a query on a list of words.

`string[] words = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}`

In my database I have a list of tracks with artist and titles. I want to concatenate all the queries with OrWhere conditions.
This is what I have for the moment :

```
var word;
var queryTracks;
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    word = words[i];
    queryTracks = db.Tracks.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(word) || c.Artist.Contains(word));
}
// all found, put all that into a list
var filteredTracks = queryTracks.ToList();
```

I already tried with the `.Concat()` method like this :

```
var word = words[0];
var queryTracks = db.Tracks.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(word) || c.Artist.Contains(word));;
for (int i = 1; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    word = words[i];
    queryTracks = queryTracks.Concat(db.Tracks.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(word) || c.Artist.Contains(word)));
}
```

But it didn't work... I just want to have all the tracks with word1, word2 and word3. Can I make a big query and then put it into a list or do I have to make list1, list2 and list3 and concatenate them ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a single query

```
string[] words = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}

IEnumerable<Track> tracks = db.Tracks.Where(c => words.Contains(c.Title) || words.Contains(c.Artist));
```